# Problema ao rodar ng build Angular

Tags: angular, build, cli

Ola, eu estou com problema no Angular quando eu rodo o seguinte comando para building no diretorio do projeto `ng build --prod --aot=false`, como eu faço para solucionar o problema?O qual e por que esta ocorrendo esse erro?
Segue abaixo o log do erro que ocorre apos executar o comando.

```
ERROR in vendor.0963fa6ef0f8a97eaa25.bundle.js from UglifyJs
TypeError: Cannot read property '_walk' of null
    at AST_Dot.eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:1112:29)
    at TreeWalker._visit (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:1513:21)
    at AST_Dot._walk (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:1111:24)
    at AST_VarDef.eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:1058:40)
    at TreeWalker._visit (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:1513:21)
    at AST_VarDef._walk (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:1056:24)
    at AST_Var.eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:966:32)
    at TreeWalker._visit (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:1513:21)
    at AST_Var._walk (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:963:24)
    at walk_body (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:513:17)
    at AST_Function.eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:739:13)
    at TreeWalker._visit (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:1513:21)
    at AST_Function._walk (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:733:24)
    at AST_Function.walk (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:467:21)
    at get_lvalues (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:8804:34)
    at collapse (eval at <anonymous> (/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:8565:35)
```

Print da imagem do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Experimente rodar o comando npm install --update-binaries --noshrinkwrap Outra coisa atualize sua versão do cli do angular

Comment: Qual comando uso pra atualizar o cli do angular

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: E mais uma questão o comando que você quer executar para buildar da maneira correta é esse 

ng build --no-aot --prod

Comment: Estou com problema em atualizar o angular cli, `npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli` ...

Comment: Se vocês estiver no windows tente executar esse comando como administrador

Comment: Estou no linux, quando eu dou um sudo antes, ele fala que deu tudo certo mas a versao do cli do angular permance inalterada

Comment: Então faça o seguinte, remova o angular cli e depois instale uma nova versão

npm remove @angular/cli -g

npm cache clean

npm i @angular/cli -

Comment: como eu faço para remover?

Comment: npm remove @angular/cli -g

Comment: Eu removi e reinstalei o cli do angular e nao mudou nada :/

Answer (score 1):

O erro que você possui aparentemente é referente a essa link do angular-cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12414#issuecomment-428161804

Ele diz que se seu projeto tiver uma dependência da biblioteca `tether` você tem que realizar o *downgrade* para a versão 1.4.3.

Ou atualizar o `terser` para a versão `3.10.7`, seguindo os passos:

- verifique a versão atual instalada do terser: `npm ls terser`
- instalar e desinstalar o `terser` com `npm install terser@3.10.7 npm uninstall terser`
- agora você deve ver a versão mais recente do terser em `npm ls terser`